# AccessViolationException thrown when I call a method imported from dll

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

In C++ header of a library there is the following code

```
#define STR_DATE        24+1    
#define STR_SIZE        32+1
#define STR_SSIZE       64+1
#define STR_MSIZE       128+1
#define STR_LSIZE       1024+1
#define STR_IPSIZE      15+1
#define STR_MOD_SIZE    20+1
#define STR_AGESIZE     4+1
#define STR_GENDERSIZE  1+1

typedef struct ADO_PINFO{   
    char    P_ID[STR_SSIZE];        
    char    F_Name[STR_SSIZE];          
    char    M_Name[STR_SSIZE];          
    char    L_Name[STR_SSIZE];          

    char    Reg_Num[STR_SSIZE];         
    UINT    nGender;                    
    UINT    nAge;                       

    COleDateTime BirthDay;              
    char    csBirthDay[STR_SIZE];       

    COleDateTime V_Date;                
    char    csV_Date[STR_SIZE];         

    char    Address[_MAX_PATH];         
    char    SubAddress[_MAX_PATH];      

    char    Telephone[STR_SIZE];        
    char    H_Phone[STR_SIZE];          

    char    csMail[STR_SSIZE];
    char    csPicName[_MAX_PATH];       
    COleDateTime InDate;
    char    csInDate[STR_SIZE];
}*PADO_PINFO;

_ADODLL long ADO_AddPatientData(const ADO_PINFO &pPatientInfo);
```

I'm trying to import the dll to my C# application:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ADO_PINFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)] public string P_ID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)] public string F_Name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)] public string M_Name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)] public string L_Name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)] public string Reg_Num;

    public uint nGender;

    public uint nAge;

    public DateTime BirthDay;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string csBirthDay;

    public DateTime V_Date;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string csV_Date;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)] public string Address;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)] public string SubAddress;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string Telephone;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string H_Phone;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)] public string csMail;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)] public string csPicName;

    public DateTime InDate;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string csInDate;
}

public class VatechLibrary
{
    [DllImport("AdodllE.dll")]
    public static extern long ADO_AddPatientData(ref ADO_PINFO patientInfo);
}
```

But when I try co call it:

```
var pInfo = new ADO_PINFO();
pInfo.P_ID = "77";
pInfo.F_Name = "name";

var res = VatechLibrary.ADO_AddPatientData(ref pInfo);
```

I get AccessViolationException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: COleDateTime is your nemesis, DateTime is *not* a substitute.  The size difference is enough to explain the AVE.  Writing a C++/CLI wrapper is *highly* advisable.

Comment: There is a lot going on in this example. I'd reduce it to the simplest example that reporduces the error and then work back. Questions/suggestions: what calling convention is _ADODLL? Try LayoutKind.Explicit and fixed field offsets. It could also be the C++ const reference. Not sure exactly how those marshall.

Comment: Explicit layout is terrible advice. Unless you love self-inflicted pain. And const reference is not an issue. That matches `ref` just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problems that I can see:

1. Your marshalling of the `COleDateTime` fields is wrong. That's because `COleDateTime` is a C++ class and they are simply not valid types for binary interop. And .net `DateTime` certainly does not match. That's surely the source of your access violation.
2. The function returns a C++ `long` which is 32 bits wide on Windows. So your C# function declaration is wrong because C# `long` is 64 bits wide. Change the return value in the C# to `int`.
3. Your C# calling convention is `stdcall`. What is the calling convention of the C++ function? That's presumably contained in `_ADODLL`. You'll need to check that it is `stdcall`. If the calling convention is not specified, it is `cdecl`.

The issue with `COleDateTime` is the big one here. The others are easily fixed. Not so for `COleDateTime`. You could change the C++ code to accept an interop friendly representation of the date. If you cannot change the C++ code to deal with the issue of item 1, then your solution will involve writing a mixed mode C++/CLI wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr`:

> Used for in-line, fixed-length character arrays that appear within a
>   structure. The character type used with ByValTStr is determined by the
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet argument of the
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute attribute applied
>   to the containing structure. Always use the
>   MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst field to indicate the size of the array.
>   .NET Framework ByValTStr types behave like C-style, fixed-size strings
>   inside a structure (for example, char s[5]).

What is your charset?  My guess is something that is unicode.

Comment: I tried using everyone available. The result is still the same.

Comment: Default charset is ANSI. This is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess I would say you need to specify the character encoding as ANSI on the struct layout in the C# strcuture declaration. ByValTStr will carry the encoding of the containing struct and based on your C++ struct using char I think you need them enoded as Ansi.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
```

From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx

> UnmanagedType.ByValTStr
>
> A fixed-length array of characters; the array's type is determined by
>   the character set of the containing structure.

Comment: It' didn't help. Still the same exception.

Comment: The default is Ansi. This changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add [Pack=1 to your StructLayout attribute.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Most of your strings/arrays are an odd number of bytes long and by default .NET will pad each of those out to an even byte boundary.

Comment: *Never* do that, a C or C++ compiler pads as well.

Comment: Never seems a bit final, surely it's necessary sometimes @HansPassant? Certainly I've had to use it on occasion although it was obviously a stab in the dark here. Is there something that we should expect to see in the header definition that would indicate when this is or isn't appropriate?

Comment: Yes, usually, the #pragma pack is typically hard to miss.  Which is why this stab is dark, that's another 10 minutes of his life he'll never get back.

Answer (score 0):

You should review the structure, the type COleDateTime is a class C++ and not have to create an attribute to interop directly. Review the items you need to access and redo the layout.